# addListeners doesn't work from time to time - React native tab navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I've used tab navigation of react-navigation. I need to call a loadData function in componentDidMount every time the tab is pressed. So I'm using addListener in it. But the problem is that it tooks too long to display the data. Sometimes it works seamlessly and sometimes it only shows "Loading Data..." all the time.
Am I using the addListener correctly? Thanks in advance.

Home.js

```
state = {
  storageCheck: true
};

componentDidMount() {
    this._unsubscribe = this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus', () => {
      this.loadData();
    });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    this._unsubscribe.remove();
}

loadData = () => {
    this.setState({
        storageCheck: false
    })
}

render() {
if (this.state.storageCheck) {
  return <View>
    <Text>Loading Data...</Text>
  </View>
}
return (
    <View>
        <Text>Data</Text>
    </View>
)}
```

## Tab navigation

```
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Home
  },
  Profile: {
    screen: Profile,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      // title: 'Profile',
    })
  },
  Setting: {
    screen: Setting,
  }
},
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        let iconName;
        if (routeName === 'Home') {
          iconName = 'home';
        } else if (routeName === 'Profile') {
          iconName = 'account-circle';
        } else if (routeName === 'Setting') {
          iconName = 'settings';
        }

        return <MaterialIcons name={iconName} size={28} color={tintColor} />;
      },
    })
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In react-navigation v4.

You can use **await-async** functions.

```js
state = {
  storageCheck: true,
  loader: true,
  someData: null
};

componentDidMount() {
    this._unsubscribe = this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus', () => {
      this.loadData();
    });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    this._unsubscribe.remove();
}

loadData = async() => {
    this.setState({
        someData: await AsyncStorage.getItem("SOME_KEY"),
        storageCheck: false,
        loader: false
    })
}

render() {
  return (
      <View>
       {this.state.someData ? (
        <Text>data is loaded</Text>
       ) : (
        <Text> loading ... </Text>
       )}
      </View>
  )
}
```

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This is a clear solution. I think you can use **hooks** and **function component**.
I use a solution related to this

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { 
    View,
    Text,
    ActivityIndicator
} from "react-native";
import { useIsFocused } from "@react-navigation/native";

const TestComp = () => {

    const [storageCheck, setStorageCheck] = useState(false);
    const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
    const isFocused = useIsFocused();

    useEffect(() => {
        const loadData = async() => {
            setStorageCheck(true);
            setIsLoaded(true);
        }
        loadData();
    }, [isFocused])


    return(
        <>
            {isLoaded ? (
                <View>
                    <Text>some data or texts..</Text>
                </View>
            ) : (
                <ActivityIndicator />
            )}
        </>
    )
}
export default TestComp;
```

cheers!

Comment: I've a older project so I cannot change it now. And I had used react navigation v4.

Comment: For v4 you should use NavigationEvents component.
`<NavigationEvents onWillFocus={() => this.fetchData()}
 {
// enter page component container
 }
</NavigationEvents>`
docs: [NavigationEvents](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/navigation-events/)

Comment: I've tried navigationEvents as well. But I've to retrieve data from async storage, which make the layout flash for a milli-second before displaying the real data. So I moved to addListener.

Comment: Have you tried this?
`loadData = async() => {
  this.setState({
      key: await AsyncStorage.getItem("SOMEKEY"),
 loader: false
  });
}`
In render func:
`render(){
 this.state.loader ? (
 <ActivityIndicator />
 ) : (
<View />
)
}`

Comment: tysm Eftal... you saved my day. Using await in the setState works great. Please include this line in the answer and I'll accept the answer.